# In java how to recognize if I am on Unix base system or windows

Tags: java, path, version

I am working on a project in `java` and I would like to know:

1. How to recognize if the path in my system uses `"/"` or `"\"`
2. Recognize the `version` of the system I running the application

I would appreciate code Sample.

Comment: If you make proper use of the File object, you don't even need to know the separator. Take a look at all the constructors java.io.File has to do the job for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two are available via [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

**Path Separator**

```
System.getProperty("path.separator");
```

**Os version**

```
System.getProperty("os.version");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
System.getProperties().list(System.out);
System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
```

System.getProperties() will give you all information you needed.

Comment: Thanks I but I don't need the full list.

Comment: try

    System.getProperty("os.name"), System.getProperty("os.version"), System.getProperty("file.separator")

Answer (score 2):

1. **file separator** under consideration:

   ```
   System.getProperty("file.separator")
   ```
2. **Operating System** being used:

   ```
   System.getProperty("os.name")
   ```

**Moreover, to get all the system properties you can use:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.getProperties().list(System.out);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this example will list all the available properties

```
public class SystemDemo {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  // this will list the current system properties
  Properties p = System.getProperties();
  p.list(System.out);
}
```

In order to get the information that you need:
**Operating System**
    p.getProperty("os.name")
**File separator**
p.getProperty("file.separator")

Answer (score 1):

1. `java.io.File.separator`;
2. System property "os name": `System.getProperty("os.name")`

Comment: this helps to determine the whole thing, but I was more specific in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
System.getProperty("file.separator"); //to get default file separator of O.S

String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
if(os.indexOf("win") >=0)
// code for windows
else if(os.indexOf("mac") >= 0)
// code for mac
else if(os.indexOf("nix") >=0 || os.indexOf("nux") >=0)
// code for linux
```

Comment: choice is yours. this is my style :) @JeanWilliamEyidi